# How to deactivate onValue.Listen for RealtimeDatabase flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a function to listen data live from my realtime database, so that when the data is changed my widget will be rebuild and show the most recent data. I manage to do that but everytime i've done changing my data there will be some error appears on my console

Error message like this:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _MainDetailCollabTicketPageState#da28c(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted).
> This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.

I've done some research and it tells me to deactivate my listener everytime I wanna close my screen. I tried to do so but there's another error

> A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'StreamSubscription?'.

Is there something wrong with my code, I tried to assign the listener before deactivating it ? how can I fix this ?

Here's my code below:

```
Screen A initState

    StreamSubscription? _powDataStream = Database.listenPowDataActive(
        ticketId: widget.ticketId,
        context: context,
        loadTicket: (value) async {
          setState(() {
            powData = value;
            powIdList = powData!.keys.toList();
          });
        }
    );
```

my Database function:

```
  static dynamic listenTicketStream(
      {required String ticketId,
      required void Function(Map) loadTicket}) async {
    _ticketsCollection.doc(ticketId).snapshots().listen((event) {
      DevMode.log("Event data is: ${event.data()}");
      loadTicket(event.data() as Map);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think is a good idea use a StreamBuilder. Just declare the StreamSubscription? _powDataStream outside iniState. Initialize that variable inside the iniState like you did (remove the async from loadTicket). The StreamBuilder will manage the stream lifecycle for you. Why do you consider use setState?